# Visualize Inclusion-Exclusion

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

Inclusion-Exclusion lets you calculate the sizes of some unions and intersections between sets knowing some of the other values. I won't explain it exactly, but your challenge is to visualize inclusion-exclusion on a Venn Diagram.

Because I'm nice, you'll be using rectangles, not circles.

You will be given a list of rectangles denoted by top-left and bottom-right corner coordinates in any reasonable format (list of 4-tuples, list of pairs of pairs, list of pairs, etc). You can assume that all coordinates are non-negative and within your language's (reasonable) number range (please specify what it is if it's less than 128). You can choose to be left-inclusive or left-exclusive and right-inclusive or right-exclusive. Regardless of your chosen format, you can assume all rectangles are at least 1x1.

Then, you are to draw out each rectangle on the screen (ASCII canvas) using a single non-whitespace character `k`, which is yours to choose.

However, whenever two rectangles overlap, the overlapping area shall be drawn with another non-whitespace character `l != k`, also yours to choose.

Whenever *three* rectangles overlap, the overlapping area should be drawn with `k`, and for an odd number of rectangles covering, `k`, and an even number, `l`.

The background should be single whitespaces (`0x20`).

## Test Cases (`k = "#", l = "."`)

```
0 0 9 9
1 1 10 10
2 2 11 11

#########  
#........# 
#.#######.#
#.#######.#
#.#######.#
#.#######.#
#.#######.#
#.#######.#
#.#######.#
 #........#
  #########

1 1 3 3
2 2 4 4


 ## 
 #.#
  ##

1 1 9 9
2 2 8 8
3 3 7 7


 ########
 #......#
 #.####.#
 #.####.#
 #.####.#
 #.####.#
 #......#
 ########
```

## Notes

- Leading spaces and newlines (which occur if the minimum coordinate isn't `0, 0`) must be present
- Any trailing spaces and newlines are allowed to a reasonable extent (i.e. don't trail like 100000000 newlines, that's just annoying)
- x- and y- axes can face either way but you must be consistent and specify which (default is x- right and y- down)
- coordinates can be 0-, 1-, or 2- indexed.

[Reference Proton Implementation](https://tio.run/##hVDbaoMwGL5unuIjV8nWhaqUtgP3Ii4XoumaYZMQHbMUn90l1g07Bgv8EL7Tf3DedtaMY2Wtr7UpO9UiRyHJ50k3Ctq4j45xPL2g0UbhSlYLpSidU6Zm59Ixbbr1pBGta3TwcE4G8uZ1HfMKCirxgHPZs75IJY7Wo8czFml8AnUANxBilmZ/SyWJaHWPxul@xMVGxpQqNgv4RFwmIpmJ7Eas9BFxzKKXxUUiz1GdPMu2HNc7HFRQDNGgmlb9Jr89URBqCLs7H27CKMKjeAR9NdNXvFttppPFajvPIznj6@WS4YK3DP5/Fp39caiFcRwTJDjgQFKk2GNPMmTYYUfIFw)

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the objective is to have the shortest code. Happy golfing!

Comment: x-axis extends rightwards and y-axis extends downward from the top-left corner?

Comment: @user202729 In test cases, yes (actually ambiguous) but you may use either as long as you're consistent

Comment: @dzaima Yup. [...]

Comment: So, `x2` and `y2` are the respective first coordinates **not** part of the rectangle?

Comment: @FelixPalmen ? I don't get what you mean

Comment: @JoKing yes, i will make the input format more flexible. realized that this is an old challenge and i wasn't too familiar with challenge writing yet

Comment: @JoKing Will clarify, they are half-inclusive (lost that meaning when I reworded my input); that is, `[x1, x2)`.

Comment: @JoKing Actually I will allow any of the four combinations.

Answer (score 4):

## [6502 machine code](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/6502_Assembly) routine (C64), 57 bytes

```
20 44 E5 A0 03 84 FB 20 9B B7 A4 FB 96 22 C6 FB 10 F5 85 FC A6 24 20 F0 E9 A4
25 B1 D1 09 01 49 02 91 D1 C8 C4 23 D0 F3 E8 E4 22 D0 E9 A9 2C C5 FC F0 D0 A5
C6 F0 FC C6 C6 4C 44 E5
```

This is position-independent code, put it somewhere in RAM and use the correct start address calling it with `sys`.

**[Online demo](https://vice.janicek.co/c64/#%7B"controlPort2":"joystick","primaryControlPort":2,"keys":%7B"SPACE":"","RETURN":"","F1":"","F3":"","F5":"","F7":""%7D,"files":%7B"incexc.prg":"data:;base64,AMAgROWgA4T7IJu3pPuWIsb7EPWF/KYkIPDppCWx0QkBSQKR0cjEI9Dz6OQi0OmpLMX88NClxvD8xsZMROU="%7D,"vice":%7B"-autostart":"incexc.prg"%7D%7D)** (start address `$C000` / `49152`).

**Usage:** `sys<startaddress>,<x1>,<y1>,<x2>,<y2>[,<x1>,<y1>,<x2>,<y2>[,...]]`

**Example:** `sys49152,0,0,9,9,1,1,10,10,2,2,11,11`

On reasonable number ranges: The natural range on this 8-bit machine is [0-255], and the program will accept this as parameters. But the C64 screen only has 40 columns and 25 rows, therefore limiting the **reasonable** range to [0-40] for x values and [0-25] for y values. Using other values will have unpredictable behavior.

---

**commented disassembly listing:**

```
20 44 E5    JSR $E544           ; clear screen
 .mainloop:
A0 03       LDY #$03            ; index for reading coordinates
84 FB       STY $FB
 .inputrect:
20 9B B7    JSR $B79B           ; read 8bit value from parameter
A4 FB       LDY $FB
96 22       STX $22,Y           ; and store to $22-$25
C6 FB       DEC $FB
10 F5       BPL .inputrect      ; parameter reading loop
85 FC       STA $FC             ; store last character
A6 24       LDX $24             ; load y1
 .rowloop:
20 F0 E9    JSR $E9F0           ; get pointer to screen row in $d1/$d2
A4 25       LDY $25             ; load x1
 .colloop:
B1 D1       LDA ($D1),Y         ; load character at screen position
09 01       ORA #$01            ; set bit 0 ( -> '#')
49 02       EOR #$02            ; toggle bit 1 (toggle between '#' and '!' )
91 D1       STA ($D1),Y         ; store character at screen position
C8          INY                 ; next x
C4 23       CPY $23             ; equals x2?
D0 F3       BNE .colloop        ; no -> repeat
E8          INX                 ; next y
E4 22       CPX $22             ; equals y2?
D0 E9       BNE .rowloop        ; no -> repeat
A9 2C       LDA #$2C            ; load ','
C5 FC       CMP $FC             ; compare with last character from parsing
F0 D0       BEQ .mainloop       ; if ',', repeat reading coordinates
 .waitkey:
A5 C6       LDA $C6             ; load input buffer size
F0 FC       BEQ .waitkey        ; and repeat until non-empty
C6 C6       DEC $C6             ; set back to empty
4C 44 E5    JMP $E544           ; clear screen
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>218</s> <s>192</s> <s>189</s> <s>185</s> <s>158</s> <s>154</s> 147 bytes

```python
def f(l):_,_,a,b=map(range,map(max,zip(*l)));print'\n'.join(''.join((' '+'#.'*len(l))[sum((x<=i<X)*(y<=j<Y)for x,y,X,Y in l)]for i in a)for j in b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY9ha4NADIa/@ysO9uESF8qpLW03/R8tnRRLdTvRU1wHuj/vklMoDN5wb3JPcrl@enx1Lp7ne1mpChp8u9KVCrplbdHDULjPksS1xUi/toewQcT3frDuoT@c3tSddaDXE7TSr/plo8OmdDwLL98/LcCYZjY9YQhTmtXpGatuUCNNdKKzsk41mEvFii/8ZS32hnMFlwAMKZY6SiAFEJESGQnJY1KsSGoR5hgEvmuhEtaT2bL@Ezz2@CQOLMkS37pned5/N1i3McRv7ZZNDG0pXmzC1ld3XN0v9iCwWWHDCHduOclx/gM)

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 40 bytes

```
ＷＳ«≔Ｉ⪪ι ιＦ…§ι⁰§ι²«Ｊκ§ι¹ＵＭＫＤ⁻§ι³§ι¹↓§10Σλ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYzBbsIwEETP8VesctqVgmSnJ9oTggtISKjpD1jBDSucdZQ4gFTx7W4ol1DNXmZm59Un29fB@pSuJ/YOcCvdGKvYszRIBD8qWw0DN4JrO0SsOs8RuYAccqICmD5U9h16wE8rjcNV3MrR3R4feqpntqQnLduNbfcV8PzSGnqAsr3t1qFtrRzx4Nx5w72rIwfBPcs4zOlv9H9fwPsmXGWW50bnBVRji57@@Hd1T0mDhiUslYFJejpVQglmMkalxcX/Ag) Link is to verbose version of code. <s>Will be 6 bytes shorter once @ASCII-only fixes a bug in Charcoal</s>. Takes input as a newline-terminated list of space-separated list of co-ordinates. Explanation:

```
ＷＳ«
```

Loop over each line of input until a blank line is reached.

```
≔Ｉ⪪ι ι
```

Split the line into a list of co-ordinates.

```
Ｆ…§ι⁰§ι²«
```

Loop over all the X co-ordinates.

```
Ｊκ§ι¹
```

Jump to the top of the column.

```
ＵＭ
```

Map over each of...

```
ＫＤ⁻§ι³§ι¹↓
```

... all the cells in the column...

```
§10Σλ
```

... the new value is `0` if they contain `1`, otherwise `1`. Edit: Soon after writing this, Charcoal changed the behaviour of `¬` so that `Ｉ¬Σλ` works here to save 1 byte.

Comment: :| did i mess something up https://tio.run/##XY7LasMwEEXX1ldcvBqBCn7k2a5CskkhEOr@gHBUR0SWjC0ngZJvV@OUQtzlzD33zJRH2ZZOmhAuR20UaGub3he@1bYizvHNolXX6crSWnaeisZoT1ogRsy5gOZvLHrv6@bTUSKw8lt7UNcByPkQ7e8eTwN8H75cC/qQtlL0BCZ81Mv479U/62mUpg9rtJPN2tW1tAfaK3Xa6FaVXjtLO237jkZv/O8LvG7cxT7t4zSJBYq@JsMf/hu7hZAgwRJLliLFAguWIcMcc5YjxwwzNsEEU0xZeDmbHw

Comment: @ASCII-only Bug in my workaround - I can print an `\n` instead I guess...

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>36</sup> 34 bytes

```
(' ','#.'$~#){~[:+/(-@]{.-~$1:)/"2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7RasIwFIbv@xQ/WohlNrZVUMsGY4OBIF7I7sYuuibVji5H2mRMhL56TcKYF@M7gXPId37O5zDirMJDDoYpEuT2xRzP@@3LMGFgUzbmLOzH0aV/y@9mk/jx/cLjPkzzaDbKhijYPXFs2LdEIYQU@KAf2aFoySgBfZQgo09Go6IWZVO0tT7D75Bqzhx4tUpHjdE1KVRGlb6pOyjSOLUkTFmrg0v64kEgyyPhHhXmyCyhPTbB2oLUkbjyP6md0pue/erOmlv8uMDif6Az1n8xK4tfWGI5XAE)

*-2 bytes thanks to Bubbler*

We take input as a list of 2x2 matrices.

- For each of them `"2`, draw a box of ones `1:` of the same shape `$` as the element-wise difference between the top-left and bottom-right coords `-~`.
- Then rotate that down and to the right with 0 fill `-@]{.` until the upper leftmost `1` is in the coords specified by the left arg `-@[`.
- `[:+/` Sum the resulting matrices element-wise.  J guarantees they will be the same size by adding 0 fill to the right.  This will produce a single matrix with integers 0, 1, 2, 3, etc.  We'll use those to index into our ascii chars `{~`.
- `'#.'$~#` Repeat the pattern `#.` cyclically `$~` to the input length `#`, and then prepend a space `' ',`.

Comment: [34](https://tio.run/##ZY7RasIwFIbv@xQ/WohlNrZVUMsGY4OBIF7I7sYuuibVji5H2mRMhL56TcKYF@M7gXPId37O5zDirMJDDoYpEuT2xRzP@@3LMGFgUzbmLOzH0aV/y@9mk/jx/cLTsI/7aDbKhijYPXFs2LdEIYQU@KAf2aFoySgBfZQgo09Go6IWZVO0tT7D75Bqzhx4tUpHjdE1KVRGlb6pOyjSOLUkTFmrg0v64kEgyyPhHhXmyCyhPTbB2oLUkbjyP6md0pue/erOmlv8uMDif6Az1n8xK4tfWGI5XAE)

Comment: @Bubbler, Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 181 bytes

```python
l=input()
_,_,x,y=map(max,zip(*l))
m=eval(`[[32]*x]*y`)
for v,w,x,y in l:
 for i in range(v,x):
	for j in range(w,y):
	 m[i][j]=max(m[i][j]^1,34)
for n in m:print''.join(map(chr,n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7RCoMgFIav51N4l8ZhUA22BT2JuJLRlqEm0kr38k7ZYPBdnP@D/5xjwzotpo5RddLY10oo6qEHD6HTwhItPLylJaWiFOlu3IQiA2NNzUvPyzBQ9Fgc3mDPDSwNVi3CWckcnDDPkWzgaYsO2c5/u0PIFmsmOZt5uubJb75V0Jy@m00u6NY6adaiOM6LNCT/dZ8cGEpjZKwCnLgmOLAacOKSSKEBnDgnOP8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>196</s> 189 bytes

```r
m=matrix
x=m(scan(file("stdin")),4)
y=m(0,max(x[3,]),max(x[4,]))
n=ncol(x)
while(n){z=x[,n]  
i=z[1]:z[3]
j=z[2]:z[4]
y[i,j]=y[i,j]+1
n=n-1}
i=!y
y=y%%2+1
y[i]=' '
cat(rbind(y,'\n'),sep='')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY3BCsIwEETv@xVrQZLFCKat2Ar5kphDrYopbZS2YFLx22uKMod9zOzu9PPcqa4ae@vBq44PdeX4zbZXngzjxbqESOQEIUY70VWee50JQ3/MIxI45epHyz3B675cOnpPymvhDCJYNWlpjpPODDSR04VzA0Fb0Rj1Gxu5PNnKT1xfhdgW1us0mjE1iiGDuhp5f7buwoNgJ8dIDNenYozmWaLEEktIcY8FFpDhIUruvg)

The code reads input as stdin, arranged as a 
x1 y1 x2 y2 
tuple, where x is the column and y is the row.
I am using 1 and 2 for the overlap levels, where 1 represents an even level.

Saved 7 bytes thanks to user2390246.

Comment: A few ideas for golfing this down: 1. Is there any need to transform your matrix x? 2. Use `nrow` (or `ncol` if not transformed) instead of `dim(x)[1]` 3.  You don't need to define `i=y>0` as you only use it once.

Comment: 4. Initialise the matrix to -1 and then just use `y=y%%2` and `y[y<0]=" "`.

Comment: Thank you. I included suggestion 1 and 2. Suggestions 3 and 4 would not work because: i=y>0 is used to store the levels prior to applying the modulus, and the modulus should not be sign preserving. However, that gave me the idea to use the implicit R convention that 0=FALSE, and save two extra bytes. :)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 205 bytes

```c
x[999][999];a;b;c;d;j;k;l;m;n;main(i){for(;scanf("%d %d %d %d",&a,&b,&c,&d)>3;m=d>m?d:m,n=c>n?c:n)for(i=b;i<d;++i)for(j=a;j<c;++j)x[i][j]=x[i][j]^2|1;for(;k<n||++l<(k=0,puts(""),m);putchar(x[l][k++]+32));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY3RisMgEEXf@xUS2KDoQpI@2YnJh4gFM9JdTbRL00Jgs9@etaHlHmbmPAwXP78Qt23RUkqzD7AwAIKDACNMECFBtD5Rz34v1xuFGW260OLDkTeFKK0oB1GiKB3rjhCV62LvTlEkhV3q8ZTY89erAXzrgHO/e1AWQovZA1u0NzoY9drnZq1h7xvbtK6cTy0dVSV@HveZFgUTkUG@8dve6KIno0fODT82jMHftlWkIpLIQ01yqsyhIQ2ps9T/)

Answer (score 2):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 54 bytes

```perl6
{my@a;{@a[$^a..$^b;$^c..$^d]X+^=1}for $_;@a >>~|>>' '}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY3dCoJAEIXvfYpzsaSZLK6CGquLjxGIxvYjFJliV2L26tsseFsXZ/gGzjczXMdHYroJmxYFzNxNpZZzqSvWaM5Zc5KsOVu41IddU4il7Uewoyw1lPq8lXLhLqb1qjxEBooKHAC5wB6UdYsgQtih6sqXfr3lnR48n9/725O/9LSVjmNvCFtCpAIyYuL4T38VMhLsUzJSMlKLMRLSk5@y@QI)

Takes input as a flat list of coordinates as inclusive coordinates, i.e. `x1,y1,x2,y2,x1,y1,x2,y2...` and outputs as a list of list of characters with `k` being `1` and `l` being `0`.

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{                                                    }  # Anonymous codeblock
 my@a;    # Declare an array
      {                          }for $_;    # Loop over the input
       @a[                 ]   # Indexing into @a
          $^a..$^b             # The range of rows
                  ;$^c..$^d    # And the range of columns for each
                            X        # And for each cell
                             +^=1    # Set it to itself bitwise XOR'd with 1
                         # Cells not yet accessed are numerically zero
                                         @a >>~|>>' '   # Stringwise OR each cell with a space
                         # Cells not yet accessed are stringily empty
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 43 bytes

```
+µ>2Ḥạ
ạ1ẋ$0ẋ⁸¤;µ/€«þ/µ€z0z€0Z€Zz€0Z€ç"/o⁶Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/70FY7o4c7ljzctZALiA0f7upWMQASjxp3HFpifWir/qOmNYdWH96nf2grkFVlUAUkDaKARBScdXi5kn7@o8Ztkf///4@ONtRRMI3VUYDQIEa0iY6CBYgBpsEi5joKhoYgFoQRCwA)

## Explanation

```
+µ>2Ḥạ                                Helper Link; combines final rectangles (0 is blank, 1 is covered, 2 is uncovered)
+                                     add the two values
 µ                                    (with the sum...)
  >2                                  check if it's greater than two
    Ḥ                                 double the result (2 if it's 3 or 4, 0 if it's 0, 1, or 2)
     ạ                                absolute difference (0 should take whatever the other thing's value is, 1+1 and 2+2 should give 2, 1+2 and 2+1 should give 1)
ạ1ẋ$0ẋ⁸¤;µ/€«þ/µ€z0z€0Z€Zz€0Z€ç"/o⁶Y  Main Link
               µ€                     For each rectangle stored as [[x1, x2], [y1, y2]]
         µ/€                          For each of [a, b] = [x1, x2] and [y1, y2], reduce it by (in other words, use a dyad on a size-2 list)
 1ẋ$                                  repeat [1]            times
ạ                                                abs(a - b)
        ;                             and append to
    0ẋ ¤                              [0] repeated   times
      ⁸                                            a
            «þ/                       and reduce by minimum outer product table (take the outer product table, by minimum, of the x results and the y results)
                                      [NOTE] At this point, we have a list of matrices with 0s as blanks and 1 as covered
                 z0z€0Z€Zz€0Z€        Make all of the matrices the same size:
                 z0                   zip, fill with 0 (all matrices are the same length, but not width, and now are lists of row-wise lists of rows)
                   z€0                zip each, fill with 0 (all rows are the same length within their row-wise lists, and are now lists of row-wise lists of columns)
                      Z€              zip each (flip rows back to lists of row-lists of rows)
                        Z             zip (flip back to matrices); however, if a matrix is smaller on both axes, its rows will not be the same length
                         z€0          zip each, fill with 0 (all rows in each matrix are the same length and the value is now a list of transposed matrices)
                            Z€        zip each (the value is now a list of matrices, all the same length, filled with 0 (empty space))
                              ç"/     reduce by (vectorized) the relation in the Helper Link (to combine all of the final values)
                                 o⁶   logical OR with " "; replace 0s with spaces
                                   Y  join with newlines (formatting)
```